# how to render a nested reactive form based on the value selected from a dropdown in the parent form?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to achieve something like this in my Angular 6 application:

I have a parent form which collects some basic information. I have a **"Version"** drop-down in that form. Based on the version selected in this drop-down, I have to conditionally display different sets of input controls in the **Sub Form** tab

Snapshot of what I require :

[image]

I'm relatively new to Angular and I am confused on what approach to use for this.

I'm referring to [this](https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-valuechanges/) tutorial.

But how do I display another Sub Form on change of the version selected?

Comment: Sub Form is an array ?

Comment: No, that is another form itself.

Comment: Could you provide an example ?

Comment: lets say the user selected version 1. In this case, I need to capture certain details about version1(eg: dealer number, update date etc). And these fields vary from one version to another. So i thought of keeping them as separate forms. I was thinking i could display them conditionally based on the option selected.

Comment: have you tried something like this : const subForm = version ==1 ? yourSubForm : defaultSubForm;